# Insert the same time, it is possible to happen?

Tags: mysql, php, insert, bulk-insert

Good evening.

I have a doubt about inclusion in the database. A common example is a user account where the user names must be unique.

In the following logic:

- User enters data into a form.
- Data are collected via $ _POST (or other method)
- Before saving the data is checked if the user name is already registered
- If not, save the record, if it is, it informs the user that the username that already exists.

Example:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_tbl` WHERE `username` = '{$username}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ( mysql_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 ) {
    /* Username already exists */
    echo 'Username already exists';
} else {
    /* Username doesn't exist */
    /* a certain time is elapsed after checking */
    /* .. insert query */
}
```

My question is, in a system with high volume of requests, it is possible that between the time to check whether the user name already exists and the inclusion (if the user name does not exist), another user can do the same action in same time?

Comment: Put a `UNIQUE` index on the field - that way, no duplicates can occur even if time elapses between your query and your insert. That code looks funny - should it not be `if(mysql_num_rows($result) = 1)` - and not `> 1`? I'm no expert on PHP - just a thought!

Comment: Laughs. I know. It was a code I just copied and pasted with SQL (pure), without safety issues, because the question is not about security but the possibility of the problem occur ... Just to illustrate the question. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Or fold the lot into a single transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could end up with duplicate usernames. 
In a scenario of high incoming requests, a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) could occur.

If you want to avoid this, just put an [UNIQUE index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on your column. 
You could create a UNIQUE index on username by using this query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_USERNAME ON `user_tbl` (`username`);
```

Prior to creating this unique index, please verify that there are no duplicate entries in your table, as the index creation would fail.

When you have an unique index on this field, it will be impossible to end up with duplicate usernames. 
When a username is inserted, the table is locked during the insertion, this guarantees that a race condition would not occur.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go though I personally I have a preference for constraints to enforce business rules (like this) and indexes where they purely aid performance.  Create the constraint and a suitable index will be created if non exists, so the outcome is likely the same but the rules and intention are made more clear.

Comment: In MySQL there is very little difference - if any - between a UNIQUE index and a UNIQUE constraint. You can create either of the two, only the syntax changes. Underneath, the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a `UNIQUE` index on `(username)`.

Comment: Although this is good, please expound more on why this would or give an example